# SOAP server in ruby with WSDL

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, soap, wsdl

I need to implement a soap server in ruby for one call and also provide a WSDL. My plan is to create the WSDL myself and just provide that on a rails server with the endpoint parsing the xml.

Is that a valid path? I looked and couldn't find much other information regarding a soap server in ruby that generates a WSDL. Action web service does but was last updated in 2005, and soap4r standalone server doesn't generate a WSDL.

Comment: The Ruby community is much more focused on RESTful web services than SOAP, you'll have to do some serious searching if anything is out there...

Comment: so how did you do that ?

Comment: I wish there was an answer to this question that didn't involve "fork abandoned project X from a few years ago, update it yourself, and you might have something working" (esp. for rails 3)! The client piece seems well taken care of by savon, but the server side is another matter. Any further news since you asked this q?

Comment: the best choice for now is https://github.com/roundlake/wash_out

Answer (score 6):

Anyone else who'd be interested in a working solution to this problem should give a shot to the gem "wash_out". I have successfully developed a SOAP server with v0.8.2

Please refer to [the gem's github repository](https://github.com/inossidabile/wash_out) for source & documentation

Answer (score 2):

Try [SimpleWS](https://github.com/mikisvaz/simplews) . I was having exact same problem and found this library to be working fine. It's a layer over soap4r. Has very simple DSL.